# Curl and gotomeeting.com

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use PHP Curl to make the registrations of https://www3.gotomeeting.com/register/432624022 automatic.

Based on the corrections made by the folks, this is what I am using:

```
<?

$array=array(
    'Name_First'=>'Steve',
    'Name_Last'=>'Jobs',
    'Email'=>'steve@jobs.com',
    'Template'=>'island/webinar/registration.tmpl',
    'Form'=>'webinarRegistrationFo‌​rm',
    'WebinarKey'=>'432624022',
    'ViewArchivedWebinar'=>'false',
    'registrant'=>'',
    'RegistrantTimeZoneK‌​ey'=>'55',
);

function dump($logArray) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($logArray);
    echo '</pre>';
}

function go2webinar($array){

    $url='https://www3.gotomeeting.com/en_US/island/webinar/registration.flow';
    $url1='https://www3.gotomeeting.com/register/432624022';

    $cookie='/therightpath/cookie';
    $query=http_build_query($array);
    $c=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1');
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,$url);    
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST,count($array));
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$query);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER,$url1);

    $r=curl_exec($c);//result
    dump(curl_getinfo($c));

    if(curl_errno($c)) return curl_error($c);
    else{
        curl_close($c);
        return trim($r);
    }
}

//GotoMeeting
echo go2webinar($array);
```

---

The cookie is being saved as it should:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.gotomeeting.com    TRUE    /   TRUE    1371763493  g2mVisitor  FirstVisit%3D1340218507523%26LastVisit%3D1340227493492%26RSN%3DDEFAULT
www3.gotomeeting.com    FALSE   /   TRUE    0   g2mSession  SessionInfo%3D200000000139397572%253A2B00BFBA6275B45
www3.gotomeeting.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  abc6tY1HKr4Hh9l-3plGt
```

However, I am getting a "Webinar Unavailable" page now...

Comment: try to use curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

Comment: Also Use Tamper data to check the actual query params, I see alot more than you are trying to post, $query="Template=island%2Fwebinar%2Fregistration.tmpl&Form=webinarRegistrationForm&WebinarKey=432624022&ViewArchivedWebinar=false&registrant=&RegistrantTimeZoneKey=55&Name_First=BobS&Name_last=Gnoomw&email=asas%40cc.com&RegistrantTimeZoneKey=55";

Comment: here is a screenshot for your referenc http://i.stack.imgur.com/0meq9.jpg

Comment: Did you check if the cookies file is actully being written ? use my script for reference, Its working ..

Comment: Also make sure you sen the cookie path properly, 

$mypath = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '/', $mypath);
$cookie = "$mypath/cookie.txt";

Comment: You should post into  $url = 'https://www3.gotomeeting.com/en_US/island/webinar/registration.flow';
NOT $url1='https://www3.gotomeeting.com/register/432624022';
use $url1 as referrer.

Comment: @Eswar Rajesh Pinapala, the cookie is being written normally.

Comment: The problem is with the 'Form'=>'webinarRegistrationFo??rm', in the params $array, change it to 'Form'=>'webinarRegistrationForm', these invalid characters(??) are invisible int he post above, but will be visible if you could paste the script into an editor like Notepad++

Comment: You are right; there was a little problem with those chars. Thank you, @Eswar for you terrific support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working script , I made it too hard coded, but you should get an idea of whats not working.

1. use `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);`
2. user agent `curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1');`
3. always find the correct params posted , using firebug/tamper data [image: Here is the tamper data screen shot]
4. You should post into `$url = 'www3.gotomeeting.com/en_US/island/webinar/registration.flow';`
   NOT `$url1='www3.gotomeeting.com/register/432624022';` 
   use $url1 as referrer.

   $query="Template=island%2Fwebinar%2Fregistration.tmpl&Form=webinarRegistrationForm&WebinarKey=432624022&ViewArchivedWebinar=false&registrant=&RegistrantTimeZoneKey=55&Name_First=BobS&Name_Last=Gnoomw&Email=asas%40cc.com&RegistrantTimeZoneKey=55";

   ```
    function curlit(){

       $url = 'https://www3.gotomeeting.com/en_US/island/webinar/registration.flow';
       $url1='https://www3.gotomeeting.com/register/432624022';

       $mypath = getcwd();
               $mypath = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '/', $mypath);
               $cookie = "$mypath/cookie.txt";
           $query="Template=island%2Fwebinar%2Fregistration.tmpl&Form=webinarRegistrationForm&WebinarKey=432624022&ViewArchivedWebinar=false&registrant=&RegistrantTimeZoneKey=55&Name_First=BobS&Name_Last=Gnoomw&Email=asas%40cc.com&RegistrantTimeZoneKey=55";
           $c=curl_init();

           curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1');
           curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,$url);    
           curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
           curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST,count($array));
           curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$query);
           curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
           curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
           curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
           curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
           curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
           curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url1);
           $r=curl_exec($c);//result
           dump(curl_getinfo($c));

           if(curl_errno($c)) return curl_error($c);
           else{
               curl_close($c);
               return trim($r);
           }
       }
       function dump($logArray) {
           echo "<pre>";
           print_r($logArray);
           echo "</pre>";
       }

       //GotoMeeting
       curlit();

       ?>
   ```

Comment: It looks something is still missing... If I echo the result form Curl, I get a "Webinar Unavailable"...

Comment: I tested this now, http://idlenri.info/curlgtm.php?fname=rajsh&lname=pina
i was able to register!

Comment: If you can get, I can also. Working on it.

Comment: Just make the changes I mentioned. See if you are missing any of the points i mentioned. and you will get it.

Comment: i just commented on the question, check it out for solving your problem.